# Show all variables and their values in VBA during runtime

Tags: vba, global-variables, runtime

In my current project in Access VBA, I created a window which works like a console and now I am trying to add a possibility to display any public variable. It should work like:

```
Show_var [variable_name]
```

So it should be like in the direct window where i can type:

```
? pVar.variable_A
```

I found out that using

```
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(11).CodeModule.CountOfLines
```

I can display the number of lines within a module or form so I thought perhaps I could somehow find the variables there, cycle through them and when the correct one is found, its value can be shown. OFC I could make a `Select Case` Statement where all variables are included but that is not the way I want to do it because it is complicated and must be changed every time update my public variable list.

Comment: I see 1000s of problems but I don't see what do you want to solve with your attempt. Content of variables can be interesting only for debugging, and for that the debugger gives you enough tools already (Immediate window, locals window, watch window)

Comment: During development i use the immediate window, sure and that's completely fine. I have users running the Software in MS-Access and they do not have the "developer" Version installed and sometimes when they are using the application - which is currently in testing Phase - Problems do occur and it would be very useful if I could check the content of certain variables which is not possible at that moment.

Comment: Longer & tedious way to do it would be create a directory with a file to write to. Then calling the sub/function to print the desired variable to the file as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems that I think you are out of luck. Let me just list some of them:

- There is no way to get a list of all variables - that would mean you would need access to the internal symbol table.
- As a consequence, you would have to read the code (`CodeModule` lets you read the code of a module), and write an own parser to fetch all declarations (hopefully you use `Option Explicit`)
- AFAIK, the is no method that can access the content of a variable via it's name.
- Even if there would be any such method: What would you do with different data types, arrays and especially with objects.
- If a user runs into problems, often it is a runtime error. If you don't handle that errors with some kind of error handler, the only option if a user cannot enter the debugger is to press "End" - which would destroy the content of all variables.
- You have to deal with scope of variables, you can have several variables with the same name and you will likely have lots of variables that are out of scope in the moment you want to dump them.

Comment: I was aware of all these problems but I thought there might be some kind of possibility to realize this. I created a very good and precise error handling routine which writes erros to the database and i can review all these errors easily when the software crashes. Sometimes it just has a strange behaviour and this is the Point where I would like to show the value of some variables during runtime. Would have been great but I see it is not possible. Thanks for your reply.